# Oldest Reference to Astronomical Seeing

Tags: atmospheric-effects

I'm writing a paper on astronomical seeing. Sir Isaac Newton identified both the phenomenon and origin of [astronomical seeing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_seeing) in his Opticks. He writes:

> If the Theory of making Telescopes could at
> length be fully brought into Practice, yet there would
> be certain Bounds beyond which Telescopes could
> not perform. For the Air through which we look
> upon the Stars, is in a perpetual Tremor; as may be
> seen by the tremulous Motion of Shadows cast from
> high Towers, and by the twinkling of the fix'd Stars.

is anyone aware of any older reference from Gilbert, Galileo, Harvey, Ptolemy, Copernicus or Kepler?

Comment: You may also want to try asking this question in the [astronomer's Facebook group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/123898011017097).

Comment: As you probably already knew, Ptolemy's "Optics" computes refraction angles, but treats these as constant.

Comment: This could be asked at the History of Science and Mathematics SE: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Robert Hooke's [Micrographia](https://books.google.com/books?id=ISP_gRwuz94C&pg=PA255&dq=twinkling%20stars%20air&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBjJG1t-bLAhVH8CYKHakfD5cQ6AEILTAD#v=onepage&q=twinkling%20stars%20air&f=false) from 1664 has a detailed discussion of "seeing"

The table [of contents], which is at the end of the book, explains that pages 230-232 discuss:

> that the Air near the Earth is composed of parts of differing density...this property produces the effects of waving and dancing of Bodies; and of the twinkling of the Stars